# How can we modify the heartbeat synchronization time of the etcd cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I want to modify `heartbeat-interval` of embedded etcd cluster running on kubernetes, I know while installation we can do with kubeadm extraargs but how to do in running cluster?

Before modifying I want to know current values too.

**EDIT1:**
To get existing value use following

```
kubectl -n kube-system  logs  etcd-<NodeHostName> |grep heart
2021-06-25 11:08:31.612468 I | embed: heartbeat = 100ms
```

I also tried below but its not working for `k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0`

```
kubectl -n kube-system exec etcd-<NodeHostName> -- env|grep "ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found following way to configure heartbeat

edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml on each etcd node and add `heartbeat-interval` and `election-timeout` like following, it will restart etcd so add one by one with delay so you should not lose quorm.

```
- command:
    - etcd
    - --advertise-client-urls=https://x.x.x.x:2379
    - --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
    - --client-cert-auth=true
    - --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
    - --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://x.x.x.x:2380
    - --initial-cluster=x.x.com=https://x.x.x.x:2380
    - --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
    - --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://x.x.x.x:2379
    - --listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381
    - --listen-peer-urls=https://x.x.x.x:2380
    - --name=x.x.x.x.com
    - --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
    - --peer-client-cert-auth=true
    - --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
    - --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --snapshot-count=10000
    - --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --heartbeat-interval=500
    - --election-timeout=5000
```